# Getting concrete array values from a model

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using Z3 to check the satisfiability of a formula in the array property fragment. The models for array variables that Z3 returns are usually expressed using other if-expressions, if-then-else case analysis, etc. I want to somehow parse the model that Z3 outputs and create the array, which satisfies the input SMT-LIB formula, explicitly.

For example I want to be able to somehow always simplify the model that Z3 outputs to the following form:

```
A -> {
  1 -> 3
  2 -> 4
  else -> 6
}
```

Is there some easy way to traverse the model (using C API?) and create an explicit array representing the model ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the output format described in your message is not expressive enough to describe models for every satisfiable formula in the array-property fragment. For example, consider the following simple example.

```
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)

(assert (forall ((i Int) (j Int)) (=> (<= i j) (<= (f i) (f j)))))
(assert (< (f a) (f b)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The formula `f` is non-decreasing, and it has two points `a` and `b` s.t. `f(a) < f(b)`. In any model, we must have that for all values `i <= a`, `f(i) <= f(a)`, and for all values `j >= b`, `f(b) <= f(j)`. That is,

`f(i) <= f(a) < f(b) <= f(j)`.

A single `else` will not work. Z3 produces an interpretation for `f` that is essentially a "step-function". You can try the example above [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/u871).